# Track specific user actions with some analytics package

Tags: analytics, user-experience

I am looking for a way to track user actions in a website. I m talking about specific users.
I would like to search for user@domain.com and get a log or something that looks like this:

user@domain.com performed action A 3 minutes ago 
user@domain.com performed action B 5 minutes ago etc.

I understand that I cannot use Google Analytics as described above due to the T&Cs so I was wondering if there is some other analytics framework which allows that.

I would really like to avoid storing everything myself due to the amount of data that I can get.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a service which needs user@domain.com to register and you/your company has a contractual relationship with this user, you are allowed to store data like this **after having the user agreed to that**.

And this doesn't depend on the tool you use (GA, home grown database PIWIK, what else) as this is a privacy issue and not a "with what shall I do this" - issue.

Finally: fortunately Google Analytics **can** do that. Have a look at custom variables and custom metrics within the doc.

Comment: It goes without saying that all privacy-related issued have been taken care off. This is a question around the technology.

Comment: Clear. Than you may really go with GA. Take a look at custom variables. One may take the email and the other the action. And this will give you the requested report on the fly: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables